# De-spiking a non-periodic signal

Tags: python, plot, signal-processing

I am working on a set of data `(x={time},y={measure})` that comes out from an instrument, but sometimes the source cause a spike on data, which cause an incorrect plot and can cause mistakes in calculating features like max and min.

So I need to remove these spikes from my data, for examples the spikes surrounded by the red circle in the image:

[image: image link]

I have found [this example](https://github.com/melizalab/quickspikes) for de-spiking but I don't know how to invert the signal (and if it's correct on a non-symmetric signal) and I think it's just for detecting the spikes and I need to remove them with operations like fitting etc...

I need help to know if there are better ways to accomplish my task or if i have simply to adapt the example above to my situation (in that case I'll need help because I have no idea how to do it).

Comment: maybe a max derivative condition, also looks like 'spikes' are single samples?

Comment: the spikes are not single samples, but a small percentage compared to others in this case.
Anyway i'll try with this smoothing filter and threshold, @MadPhysicist could you gently link me some guide or examples for this operations? Many thanks!

Comment: This is a legit on-topic question on the programming end of [tag:signal-processing] and should not be closed.

Comment: It does look like a noisey sensor.  Before you filter, know that filtering will add in it's own errors (from latencies).   For a problem like this, I would recommend breaking it into two pieces (anomony detection and anomoly repair).   To minimize errors, the anomolous data can be replaced by an adaptive replicate for the segment.  This way, you have the best guess for the anomolous zones and real data where you did not detect anomolies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a set of steps you can follow to estimate the location of peaks:

1. Smooth the data. Any number of filters are available for this. An excellent starting point is the `smooth` function described in the [scipy cookbook](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/SignalSmooth.html). It will be up to you to select the appropriate parameters like window size:

   ```
   baseline = smooth(data, ...)
   ```
2. Treat the smoothed data as a baseline, sort of like a best fit line in the absence of a known fitting function. Subtract the baseline from the data:

   ```
   noise = data - baseline
   ```
3. The result is essentially a rough estimate of the noise about your pseudo-fit. Set a threshold and chop of the parts where the noise is too much:

   ```
   threshold = 3.0 * np.std(noise)
   mask = np.abs(noise) > threshold
   ```

There are plenty of configuration options to play with here: smoothing filter type and window size, threshold factor and even metric. E.g., you can use IQR or something entirely different instead of standard deviation. What you do with the masked points is also entirely up to you. Common options are to discard entirely or to replace with the baseline values.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the solution seems to working, but i have encountered a problem, after the smooth function the baseline has a different number of points than the data; is that normal?
I can say it's working cause i have printed the baseline after smoothing in a graph with **x=plt.linspace(1,len(baseline),len(baseline))**, but for doing the **data - baseline** i need them to have the same number of samples.

Comment: I think that's a separate question. I have no idea exactly what you did, so it's hard to say what went wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you extracted the data-baseline points into another array by using the mask. If so, then the new array is smaller. You would then need to mask off the "x" value array in your plot in a similar fashion - essentially preserving the one to one mapping of the original X, Y pairs and the new filtered X, Y pairs.

Answer (score 1):

There are outliers that you want to remove, and there are many ways to do it. The main goal is to detect them, and further to replace them with the estimated values, based on the neighbouring samples.

The simplest, and arguably most effective approach is to find running differences of successive samples, and compare them against some predetermined threshold. Here you have to be careful about determining the size of the threshold, since that will determine the sensitivity and accuracy of your algorithm.

The second solution could be to simply use a low pass filter, but I recommend using linear phase filtfilt for it scipy.signal.filtfilt.

Another sort of a filter may be used, and the median filter is probably the best bet: scipy.signal.medfilt.

I hope that this answer your question, and that you will be able to find filter coefficients for your case.

Comment: agree on ``scipy.signal.medfilt`` for that specific use case